# How to config file sts.ini with RAM 8GB for sts 3.5.0?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my file "sts.ini", I configed but it something still run very slow.
Who can help me please?

> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
>   4096M
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
>   -Xms1024m
>   -Xmx2048m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are trying to change the PermSize (see that you put it twice!!). If you want more ram you have to change the Xmx and Xms

example:

> -Xms4g
>   -Xmx8g
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

That way you get up to 8gb of ram and start with 4gb.

Hope it helps!